# How to encode multiclass target variable?

Tags: multi-class, multilabel, dependent-variable

I have a ML project for classifying news articles. In my dataset I have a target variable called "category", which represents type of the article, ("IT", "Science & Tech", "News", "Health", etc...) .

I'm struggling to find the best approach to encode it. The only relevant post I found is https://towardsdatascience.com/target-encoding-for-multi-class-classification-c9a7bcb1a53

Post is great, however I still do not have a clear picture on how to use technique, provided by the author, as now I have not 1 but N number of target variables (see the article).

Could someone give recommendations on how to properly encode multiclass target variables?

Comment: What's wrong with a multinomial model?  Ie an integer encoding from 0 to N-1, for N categores